# Does publishing app in alpha/beta testing unpublish my app in Production?

Tags: android

I have an already published app in production with good number of downloads, but now i want to upgrade my app by adding some functionality which need to test before testing. But it seems that when i go the link given in beta testing option it gives me the old apk, as the version in the setting is the old one. When i cross checked in developer console i saw that in beta my apk in still in draft. So my question is that if i publish the app which is in beta version, will i loose my already published app which is there in production? as i am getting constant downloads on my already published app. so i fear that if i publish the modified app in beta for the tester it will remove the old version working version of the app which is already in prod. and available to users ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you publish a new version in beta, only those users that are part of the beta testers group will see the new version.

All the other users will continue downloading the previous version until you promote your beta to production.

Answer (score 4):

FYI, beta testing APK and real production APK, both are different.

As you have mentioned, you have beta-testing enabled so only those users who are in beta testers group can download latest APK.

And those who have downloaded app from app store can update App only when you move your beta testing app to production.

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

No it will not affect. Because it will be in "play.google.com/testing" and production will be in "play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="your package name" so when you switch over to production only, users can download updated application.